# Get current directory of process

Tags: c#, process

How Can I get information like the working directory of an external process in C#?

For example there is a node.JS process and I'd like to get it's working directory.

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16142791/2557128) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask a question please at more information and what you already have tried!!
However see code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
string fullPath = process.MainModule.FileName;
```

Hopes this will help also see official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: This does not work. It shows the path of the process application, but not of the working directory.

Comment: What would you expect 'with working' directory do you have a example path?

Comment: For example if I run node ./example.js from C:/workplace/ the working directory would be C:/workplace/ and not the application path, where node.exe is installed.

Comment: Did you already take a look at the documentation? Because there are all the possible ways located. Including processes from remote computers in your local network.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Path of any running Process try this.

> Function

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName([In] IntPtr hProcess, [In] uint dwFlags, [Out] StringBuilder lpExeName, [In, Out] ref uint lpdwSize);

public static string GetMainModuleFileName(this Process process, int buffer = 1024)
{
    var fileNameBuilder = new StringBuilder(buffer);
    uint bufferLength = (uint)fileNameBuilder.Capacity + 1;
    return QueryFullProcessImageName(process.Handle, 0, fileNameBuilder, ref bufferLength) ?
    fileNameBuilder.ToString() :
    null;
}
```

> Usage

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Process").First();
string path = process.GetMainModuleFileName();
```

Hope it helps.