# In perl how to get current directory path of any process?

Tags: windows, perl

In Perl, I want to get the current working directory of any process.

e.g. We have command "pwdx" in unix which gives current working directory of a process.

I want similar "pwdx " in perl.

Please let me know any Perl command which gives me current working directory of a process.

Note: I am on Windows platform and not in Unix platform.

Regards,

Amol

Comment: Is $ENV{PWD} not set on windows?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the details about a process (along with current working directory) with `wmic` or `handle` shell commands, as described in this question: [windows batch command to determine working directory of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576834/windows-batch-command-to-determine-working-directory-of-a-process)

Then you could use that command with backticks (``) to get the output and use a regex to get the current working directory.

Note: I'm not on windows so I can't test the commands.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [Win32::Process](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Win32::Process) modules.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to use the same.